# Can Liferay divide a HTML email template into logical sections

Tags: liferay

I would like to know whether Liferay can divide email templates into logical sections and manage these sections. Furthermore I would like to manage the email templates with Liferay's content management system.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What kind of emails are you talking about? Emails for your own portlet or emails for some functionality from Liferay (_forgot password_ or similar)?

Comment: alternatively discussed on the liferay forums. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/61659563 Anywhere else?

Comment: Hello Tobisa Liefke, thank you for your response. I am looking for some functionality from LifeRay. I want to edit HTML Email templates in an editor ( An Editor which hopefully LifeRAy provides as an existing portlet). Furthermore I would like to manage the edited HTML Email template files ( LifeRay provides document managing). I would like to have also the possibility to manage certain sections from an edited HTML Email template ( for instance to save only the body of an HTML Email template or create a new HTML Email template from already existing sections from a body section etc).

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't noticed about your question - please read [how do comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). And you didn't answer my question - you simply repeated your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay contains email template in tmpl files, which are not manageable like WCM, So in case if you want to change or manage that templates then you need to create class level hook. For that you have to create a path in hook xml, which indicate that your template will placed in /root/web-inif/classes folder of tomcat server. then need to restart your server. After that your changes will reflect.

XML file path.

```
\ROOT\WEB-INF\
```

and hook folder structure will be upto the **classes** folder.

Comment: Hello Ashish Dadhich, thanks for your comment. Does LifeRay provide some functionality to manipulate html email templates ? I would like to have the possibility to separate an html email template into logical sections (for instance separate header, picture, content of the body, foot etc.) . After that step of separating, I would like to save these separated logical sections (as some kind of, lets say snippet), which I can use for a new html email template.

Comment: No, That type of functionality not given by Liferay builtin.

Comment: If you want to customize Liferay template then you need to hook that... otherwise if its custom template then you can store in your DB and use ckeditor to edit that template...

Comment: Hello Ashish Dadhich, thank you for your response. I have one or more questions about a "hook". What happens if a hook does not give me the functionality, I am looking for ? Does that mean that I have to develop a portlet instead of a hook ?

Comment: Yes, In that case you need to create your own portlet. with services for storing template in DB. like CURD operations.

Comment: Hello Ashish Dadhich, thanks again for your helpful response. How do I know what a hook can do and what it can not do ? What is the limit of a hook ? If a hook is limited, then I will start using/developing a portlet.